# Is there a common name for a "craft" beer brewed by a major brewery?

Tags: terminology

A fake grassroots organization (one sponsored by an industry but made to look as though it was set up by regular people) is called an "astroturf" group. Is there a similar name for a "craft beer" that's actually produced by one of the big brewers (AB InBev, SABMiller, etc.)?

Said another way, what do you call a beer that is made to look as though it was brewed by a small, independent brewery but was really produced by a major brewer?

Examples might be Blue Moon (SABMiller) or ShockTop (AB InBev).

Comment: @MsKensington's answer is good, and the term that I've heard/used the most is "crafty."

Comment: "Crafty" [as described by the brewers association](http://www.craftbeer.com/news/craftbeer-com-news/craft-vs-crafty-a-statement-from-the-brewers-association)

Comment: I got fooled by one of those the other day. I feel so dirty now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Wisconsin, there is not a coined term for those types of "craft brews" as produced by a global brewery.  They are generally referred to simply by describing the brew as a/an fake or impostor craft, craft-style beer, or Big Beer craft.  (The descriptors simply degenerate as the beer-passion elevates.)

This 2013 TIME article simply references "Faux Craft" and "Crafty"
http://business.time.com/2013/08/13/that-craft-beer-youre-drinking-isnt-craft-beer-do-you-care/

If it's a matter of simply communicating effectively, I don't feel the need to use a coined term (as astroturf is to grassroots).  For marketing purposes, however, it seems there is still time for a hilariously ironic name to be coined.

Comment: I was hoping for a hilariously ironic name :-) "Crafty" is okay but not great, "faux craft" is a bit clearer. Thanks for the answer!